# How can I add a text-shadow (or similar) to a caret in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used four text-shadow commands to create a faux 'stroke' in the text on my page's Bootstrap `nav-pill` navigation. The only issue I'm having is that the `caret` class used on the `span` in the pill with a drop-down does not inherit those shadows, and applying my custom shadow class to that span element does not fix it either (I'm assuming the `caret` is not 'text', per-se).

What type of character or object is the `caret` symbol in Bootstrap and can I apply shadows to it as well so it falls in line with my current design?

EDIT: I should add that I do not have the Bootstrap files on my webserver, instead I'm linking to it externally.

Comment: You can't. Have look at this ---> http://www.bootply.com/KxdzLfm5hH.

Comment: Yeah, you're right - although there is a workaround: http://css-tricks.com/triangle-with-shadow/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the triangle that Bootstrap uses is not a character but a [CSS trick](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) and so applying a `box-shadow` will put a shadow on the transparent box that is created by the border-size attribute of this trick. There are two ways to achieve the same effect: 1) use `unicode` characters such as: ▼ and applying text-styling while removing the `<span class="caret"></span>` from the `nav` menu, or 2) nesting a box inside of a container and overflowing a portion of it with styling applied.

Source: [css-tricks.com/triangle-with-shadow](http://css-tricks.com/triangle-with-shadow/)